# Looking for help when creating a copy constructor for a LinkedList class in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, copy-constructor

First, I realize that there are multiple topics about this on StackOverflow. I'm having a slight bit of trouble understanding the responses in some of them. I'm creating this in hopes that someone can help me understand the process.

I apologize if this question seems relatively novice, but I am doing my best to understand it.

I'm learning about data structures and have been asked to create a LinkedList implementation file based on a header that was provided.

**This is homework, so please no 'here is the exact code' type answers. Pseudocode, steps, and hints are welcome.**

Here is the part of the header that I'm working on at the moment:

```
typedef std::string ElementType;

class LinkedList
{
private:
   class Node
   {
   public:
      ElementType data;
      Node * next;

      Node( )
      : data( ElementType( ) ), next( NULL )
      { }

      Node( ElementType initData )
      : data( initData ), next( NULL )
      { }
   }; // end of Node class

   typedef Node * NodePointer;

public:
   LinkedList( );
   /* Construct a List object

      Precondition: none.
      Postcondition: An empty List object has been constructed.
   */

   LinkedList( const LinkedList &source );
   /* Construct a copy of a List object.

      Precondition: None. 
      Postcondition: A copy of source has been constructed.
   */

   ~LinkedList( );
   /* Destroys a List object.

      Precondition:  None.
      Postcondition: Any memory allocated to the List object has been freed.
   */

   const LinkedList & operator=( const LinkedList &rightSide );
   /* Assign a copy of a List object to the current object.


private:
   NodePointer first;
   int mySize;
};
```

So far, I've created the destructor, can you check and make sure it is correct?

```
//Destructor
LinkedList::~LinkedList() 
{ 
    NodePointer ptr = first;

    while(ptr != 0 ) {
        NodePointer next = ptr->next;
        delete ptr;
        ptr = next;
    }
    first = 0;
}
```

Now here is the part where I'm lost...What are the basic steps of creating the **copy constructor**? I've finished the default constructor which was simple, but I'm a bit confused with what I should be doing on the copy constructor.

I'm also slightly confused about overloading the = operator, I assume it will be very similar to the copy constructor.

**Edit**

My first attempt at the copy constructor:

```
LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList & source)
{
    //create a ptr to our copy
    Node * copy_node = source.first;
    //where we will be inserting our copy
    Node * insert_node = first;

    while(copy_node != nullptr) 
    {
        //insert our new copy node
        insert_node = new Node(copy_node->data);
        //move to our next node
        copy_node = copy_node->next;

        if(copy_node != nullptr) {
            insert_node = insert_node->next;
        } else {
            insert_node = first;
        }

        //update size
        mySize++;

    }
}
```

I feel like something is missing there.

Comment: `ptr != 0` and `first = 0` If you have C++11 support, you should use `nullptr` instead of the integer literal `0`, e.g. `ptr != nullptr` or simply `while(ptr)`

Comment: @DyP Thank you for that information. I wasn't aware of `nullptr`. I switched it to that since it's readability is better for me.

Comment: The simplest way to create a copy-assignment operator is to use `const LinkedList& operator=(LinkedList rhs);` (pass-by-value) and use the `first` pointer of the parameter `rhs`. Also search for copy-and-swap idiom.

Comment: `Node * insert_node = first;` This is not good (UB), as you haven't initialized `first` in your copy-ctor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most easiest way is to implement a function which adds new nodes into the list and call it in the loop inside the constructor:

```
LinkedList(const LinkedList& rhs)
{
   Node* node = rhs.first;
   while (node) {
     add(node.data);
     node = node->next;
   }
}

void add(ElementType data)
{
   Node* node = new Node(data);
   // add node somehow
   // I'd recommend to keep pointer to the tail
}
```

Please note this implementation is not exception safe!

EDIT: added copy function for the copy constructor, the first step to the exception safety:

```
LinkedList(const LinkedList& rhs)
{
  copy(rhs.first, first);
}

void copy(Node* src, Node*& dest)
{
 // handle the head element separately
 if (!src) {
   return; // empty list
 } else {
   dest = new Node(src->data); // equivalent to first = new Node...
   src = src->next;
 }

 // copy the rest of the list
 Node* p = dest; 
 while (src) {
   p->next = new Node(src->data);
   src = src->next;
   p = p->next;
 }
}
```

Comment: I've edited my original post with an attempt, am I on the right track? I've avoided an extra utility function for the time being, but I can add it if I need to.

Comment: How do you ever expect to have non-empty lists if you don't have some function to add new nodes?

Comment: You're on the right way. However, you're doing some wrong things. At the first your copied list will be lost because you don't assign anything to the 'first' node. At the second you forgot to move forward the insert_node. You're just rewriting it on every iteration of your loop.

Comment: So do I start `first` out as `NULL`? As for moving `insert_node` should I simply be setting it to `insert_node = insert_node->next`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But there's a trick, at the end of copying 'insert_node' will point to the last copied element (or even NULL if you won't check 'copy_node' on NULL before moving 'insert_node'). If you assign it to the 'first' node you will get a copy of the list containing the last element only. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the last comment. Should I be checking `if(copy_node != null) { insert_node = insert_node->next } else { insert_node = first }` I modified my original post to reflect this.

Comment: Sorry, seems that code explains better than me. :-) I added an example of the copy function. At the first part I remember the head, the second part is correct asignment/moving forward: you have to assign to the next node otherwise it makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the code. I'm unfamiliar with `*&` though, what exactly does that mean? Or was it a typo?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40474/discussion-between-dnk-and-startinggroovy)

Answer (score 3):

> What are the basic steps of creating the **copy constructor**? I've finished the default constructor which was simple, but I'm a bit confused with what I should be doing on the copy constructor.

Well, you need to copy the source, obviously.  If the source is a list of N nodes then you need to construct another list of N nodes, with each node being a copy of the corresponding one in the source.

So loop over the source nodes and create copies of them.

> I'm also slightly confused about overloading the = operator, I assume it will be very similar to the copy constructor.

Yes, except you need to dispose of the current nodes first.  However, a simple and safe way to implement assignment is copy-and-swap, so define a correct swap member:

```
void swap(LinkedList& other)
{
   std::swap(first, other.first);
   std::swap(size, other.size);
}
```

Then use it to implement assignment:

```
LinkedList& operator=(const LinkedList& source)
{
   LinkedList(source).swap(*this);
   return *this;
}
```

This creates a temporary that is a  copy of `source`, then swaps it with `*this`, so the old contents of `*this` get destroyed by the temporary, and `*this` ends up with the copied data.

N.B. the return type should be non-const, it is not idiomatic to return a const-reference from  an assignment operator.

Comment: Is there a reason to pass by reference here and create the temporary internally?

Comment: For someone who doesn't know how to implement a copy constructor it avoids introducing more concepts (rvalues vs lvalues) than needed.  The signature of an implicit copy constructor takes a const-reference, so it's the simplest form to introduce IMHO

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond. I edited my original question with an attempt on the copy constructor, can you tell me how close/far I am? As for overloading operator=, I haven't read about std::swap yet, so I'm not necessarily sure if I'm allowed to use it.

Comment: `std::swap` just swaps two values, you can do that by hand if you prefer.  Your copy constructor doesn't update `insert_node` so keeps assigning a new `Node` to the same pointer. It also doesn't update `size`, and `copy->data` should be `copy_node->data`.